# What's the chemical reaction involved when adding Caesium to water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity

According to the [Notting Hill and Ealing High School](http://www.nhehs.org.uk/chemistry/_Caesium_Water.html), the reaction of caesium $\ce{Cs}$ with water $\ce{H2O}$ gives the following equation,
$$\ce{2Cs (s) + 2H2O (l) → 2CsOH (aq) + H2 (g)},$$
producing caesium hydroxide $\ce{CsOH}$ and hydrogen $\ce{H2}$, thus it's not hard to understand why is the reaction so violent.

But I don't really understand the reaction. Is this a [single displacement reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_displacement_reaction)?

If so, why does the water break so fast into $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{OH}$ ?

Is this related to caesium's weak electronegativity? ($0.79$ on the Pauling scale)

Comment: $\ce{Cs}$ donates a single electron to a hydrogen of water and forms $\ce{Cs+,}$ $\ce{H^\bullet}$ and $\ce{OH-}$. And then, two hydrogen atoms combine to form $\ce{H2}$ gas.

Comment: So this is a redox reaction? The Cs is reducted by the hydrogen?

Comment: The oxidation number of $\ce{Cs}$ is increased from $0$ to $+1$. So, I think $\ce{Cs}$ is oxidised. s-block metals generally function as reducing agents.